# Where and How should a Kernel Panic be reported?

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, kernel-panic

I've Archlinux installed on my laptop Fujitsu Amilo Pi 2*** and I cannot find any log at `/var/log` that has the StackTrace.

The Kernel panics ALWAYS when I try to modify screen brightness.

Where are those Logs or StackTraces?

Do I have to install any package to catch that StackTrace?

Where should I send that Log/StackTrace?

Thanks for reading.

--

**UPDATE 1**
I cannot change brightness trough console:
`xbacklight -get` and any other parameter as `-dec` or `-inc` always returns:

```
[kangcoding@Pi2530Arch ~]$ xbacklight -set 100
No outputs have backlight property
```

I still cannot find log files or stacktraces of this Kernel Panic. Here is a Photo:

I cannot add a photo because I have no reputation to do that. You can see it with [enter this Dropbox URL](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hmpazmof3b5q8dk/2012-11-17%2021.41.35.jpg?dl=1)

Comment: try to change brightness being in text console, photo your kernel panic message and post here, which kernel version you run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you should report bugs to your Linux distribution's bug tracker, where experts will triage the bug and determine who needs to work on it. (In the case of Arch Linux, this would be the [Arch Linux bug tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/).)

What will happen next is that someone will come along and try to figure out if the bug originates in original code in the kernel, or from a customization that your distribution has done to it. If the latter, then they will handle it themselves. If it appears to be a bug in the original code, then they will pass it upstream (in this case, to the [Linux kernel bug tracker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/)). They may copy and paste the bug to the upstream tracker for you, or they may ask that you do it yourself.

(And of course, if you compiled your own kernel from original kernel.org sources, you can skip the Arch bug tracker entirely.)

In either case, there is a suggested [procedure for reporting Linux kernel bugs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/reporting-bugs.html) that you may want to familiarize yourself with.